# Missing strings not appearing in Stata 'count' command

Tags: stata

I'm attempting to count the number of observations in a variable with missing values. This would seem to require the following simple code:

`count if control_ == "."`

The observations in variable *control* are strings. When I run the above code, I get a "0," but when I browse the data, there are many missing values. I have also tried:

`count if control_ == " "`

What may be happening?

Comment: Also note that, if `control` were a numeric variable, the appropriate syntax would be `count if control == .` or `count if missing(control)`, without the quotation marks.

Comment: With a numeric variable `missing(control)` is also true for missing values `.a` to `.z`. Other way round, Stata doesn't regard one or more stops (periods) or one or more spaces as a missing string value. in Stata the help at  `help missing` explains all the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, `count if control_ == " "` is counting strings that are a single space. Try `count if control_ == ""` (with no space between the quotation marks).